# centos6にffmpeg-phpをインストールする際のエラーについて

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg

centos6にffmpeg-php入れようとしているのですがmake時に下記の様なエラーが出ます。

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/stat.h:107,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php_streams.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:395,
                 from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:91: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:92: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:93: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:152: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:153: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:154: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php_streams.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:395,
                 from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:367: error: array type has incomplete element type
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:374: error: array type has incomplete element type
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:401,
                 from /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:218: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'time_t'
/usr/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:246: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'time_t'
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c: In function 'zm_startup_ffmpeg':
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:94: warning: implicit declaration of function 'avcodec_init'
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

情報は少ないですが、何で怒られているか教えていただけますでしょうか

Comment: いったい何を実行して出たエラーなのですか？インストール手順を教えて頂けますか？

Comment: ディレクトリ名から察するに ffmpeg-phpのビルドを行っているように見えますが… ffmpeg ではなく ffmpeg-php をインストールしたいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーが出ているのはOSが持っているデータの形に関するものなのでビルドシステムがOS種別を誤解しているように思われます。

FFmpegのbuildGuide https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos
によると、ffmpegを./configureする際にPKG_CONFIG_PATHを指定するように、との記述がありますのでこの辺ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ご回答有難うございます。
ご教示いただきましたように実行しましたら、エラーはなくなりました。

また、下記のエラーが出たのですが、お分かりになりますでしょうか。
x264はインストールしましたが、パスが通っていないかと思い、ライブラリのパスを変えたりしているのですが、解決できません。

```
libavcodec/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_146'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Comment: libavcodec.soの中にある外部参照が未解決と言っています。このライブラリがリンクしようとしているライブラリのバージョンの不一致と思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
バージョンの確認をしてみます、